# How to retrieve image data and display it as ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap

I am trying to retrieve my image data that has been converted from byte to bitmap.But instead of showing a picture, it is showed nothing. In the logcat, i can clearly saw my image data changed into bitmap.

Here`s my java code to save mydata

```
        items Item= new items();
        db.getWritableDatabase();
        Item.setName(name.getText().toString());
        Item.setCategory(SpCate.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Item.setDetails(details.getText().toString());
        Item.setImage(imageInByte);
        db.addItemSpinner(new items());
            // Save the Data in Database
          MyDb entry= new MyDb(SellingItem.this);
          entry.getWritableDatabase();
          entry.addItemSpinner(Item);
          entry.close();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("name", Item.getName());
            Log.d("category", Item.getCategory().toString());
            Log.d("details", Item.getDetails());
            Log.d("image", Item.getImage().toString());
            Intent i=new Intent(SellingItem.this,SearchItem.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

Here is my database to retrieve the data.

```
 public List<items> getAllContacts() {
            List<items> itemlist = new ArrayList<items>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY name";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    items item = new items();
                    item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    item.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    item.setImage(cursor.getBlob(2));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    itemlist.add(item);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // close inserting data from database
            db.close();
            // return contact list
            return itemlist;

        }
```

And this is my java code to display the data in the listview

```
 dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        db = new MyDb(this);
        List<items> Item = db.getAllContacts();
        for (items cn : Item) {
            String log = "Id:" + cn.getId() 
                    + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
            // add contacts data in arrayList
            imageArray.add(cn);

        } 
           adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,
              imageArray);
            dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
            dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                 imageName = imageArray.get(position).getImage();
                 imageid = imageArray.get(position).getId();
                 //convert byte to bitmap
                 ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                 imageName);
                    theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchItem.this,
                           DisplayDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imageid", imageid);
                    intent.putExtra("imagename", theImage);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
    });
```

And this is logcat that showed the image bitmap and id that can be read.

```
Id:2 ,Image: [B@428e21d8
```

I do not know what is wrong with my code, but i need to view that image in the listview. Any help would be appreciated.

this is my CustomListAdapter

```
package com.example.projectonline;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<items>{
    ArrayList<items> data= new ArrayList<items>();
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;

     public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<items> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ImageHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new ImageHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            items picture = data.get(position);
            holder.txtTitle.setText(picture.name);
            //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

            byte[] outImage=picture.image;
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
            return row;

        }

        static class ImageHolder
        {
            ImageView imgIcon;
            TextView txtTitle;
        }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code for your CustomListAdapter

Comment: I added my CustomListAdapter above, can you check it?

Comment: Other than the fact that your code is confusing to read because you don't adhere to standard naming conventions (i.e. class names start with an uppercase letter, variable names start with a lowercase letter), and because of the extra, needless variables that you create (e.g. `View row = convertView;`), it all looks ok. You should probably do something to verify that your Bitmaps are actually valid images.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will search more in that area